# Why can't Guy Pearce travel forward in time with his fiance in the movie Time Machine?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-time-machine-2002

In the movie Time Machine, Guy Pearce's fiance keeps dying when her time comes, no matter how many time he travels back to meet her.

My question is why can't he take her on his time machine and take her past her death time so that she can survive?

Comment: I'm putting this as a comment, since I don't haven evidence to back this up (yet): I think this is explained when he travels into the future and confronts..umm.. we'll call him "the brain"; "the brain" explains that it would cause a paradox. Guy invents the time machine for the sole purpose of rescuing his fiance, if he rescues her, the time machine would cease to exist, thus meaning she couldn't be rescued. So, the paradox corrects itself by her always dying, no matter what action Guy takes.

Comment: Within the universe of the movie itself, I don't have an answer; but the mechanics presented by the sequel to HG Wells' novel ('The Time Ships') uses a parallel-timeline system to prevent paradoxes, even to the point of allowing all human history to be overwritten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Time Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Time_Machine_(2002_film))

> The Über-Morlock explains that Alexander cannot alter Emma's fate because her death is what drove him to build the time machine in the first place: saving her would create a temporal paradox. He then reveals that the Morlocks have brought the time machine underground, and tells Alexander to get into it and return home

Answer (score -1):

He simply didn't think of the solution, which would have been to go back in time and fake her death but in actuality transport her to the future at any point after he had undertaken this specific time journey. In this scenario, there would be no paradox since his pre-time machine self would have still built the machine in order to save her.